# Safari extension publish process

Tags: gallery, publish, safari-extension

I see a big difference with publishing/updating a browser extension in Safari compared to Chrome/Firefox. Particularly I have 3 questions:

1. Does safari gallery have a developer's dashboard to manage/edit/update browser extensions like in Chrome or Firefox?
2. How long does it take for the safari extension to be published in Safari Gallery?
3. Let's say I uploaded an extension v1. How to update it with v2?

Comment: This question will be irrelevant soon because Apple is going to block extension submission to Safari Extensions Gallery after December 2018.
https://developer.apple.com/safari/whats-new/

Developers are encouraged to transition to Safari App Extensions.